# RavenDB workaround for nested LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I have simple set of objects stored in RavenDB:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Supporters { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsOfficial { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to query RavenDB to give me set of questions, ordered firstly by number of supporters, next by condition - if a question has any official answer, and in the and, by question creation date. So I've written a query:

```
var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question>().AsQueryable(); 
questions = questions
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supporters.Count)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Answers.Any(a => a.IsOfficial)) //EDIT: source of exception
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
                .Take(15);                
var result = questions.ToList();
```

which throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'
```

The query is logically correct and works, when I use linq-to-objects, and simply add **.ToList()** to first line:

```
var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question>().Tolist().AsQueryable();
// next lines stay unchanged
```

I don't want to do it because of performance issues (this change forces all questions to be loaded from database into memory before filtering).

How to make this working without performance impact ? Maybe shell I define an index ? How it should looks like then ?

Comment: Have you tried your query without `ToList()` or `.AsQueryable()` just like: `var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question>().OrderByDescending();`

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?  Does it happen when ToList() is called, or when you try to access the Count of Supporters, or call to Any(), or elsewhere?  I agree with MGA that the .AsQueryable() isn't needed.  I also think an index for the Count and Any() is a good idea.

Comment: @Bear Alexander: I've edited the question and pointed the source of the error. AsQueryable() is indeed not needed. The index clue seems to be interesting. Can you post such index example, according to my case, and the modified query which preserve my logic and returns desired result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Bear Alexander response, I've done this like that:

```
public class QuestionByAnyOfficial : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Question, QuestionByAnyOfficial.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id;
        public bool AnyOfficial;
        public int SupportersCount;
        public DateTime CreatedOn;
    }

    public QuestionByAnyOfficial()
    {
        Map = questions => from question in questions                               
                           select new
                              {
                                  Id = question.Id,                                              
                                  AnyOfficial = question.Answers.Any(a => a.IsOfficial),
                                  SupportersCount = question.Supporters.Count,
                                  CreatedOn = question.CreatedOn
                              };            
    }
}

var questionIds = DocumentSession.Query<QuestionByAnyOfficial.Result, QuestionByAnyOfficial>()
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.SupportersCount)
                       .ThenByDescending(x => x.AnyOfficial)
                       .ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
                       .Take(NumberOfQuestions)
                       .Select(x => x.Id);
var questions = DocumentSession.Load<Question>(questionIds);
var result = questions.ToList();
```

It works and I believe it is more efficient than my original version. If it can be done in any more elegant way, I'd appreciate any ideas. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

A custom index for your purposes is basically going to be a recreation of your class with extra fields in it (and some logic to support it).  It seems like you don't want to have to add more fields to your current class, are you okay with adding more classes to your project?

Here's an example:

```
public class Question_WithAnyOfficial: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Question>
{
    public class Question_WithAnyOfficial()
    {
        Map = questions => from question in questions
                           // New Anonymous Type
                           select new
                           {
                                Id = question.Id,
                                CreatedOn = question.CreatedOn,
                                Supporters = question.Supporters,
                                Answers = question.Answers,
                                AnyOfficial = question.Answers.Where(a => a.IsOfficial).Any()
                           };
    }
}
```

Then you can query this:

```
var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question_WithAnyOfficial>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supporters.Count)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.AnyOfficial)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
                .Take(15)
                .ToList();
```

Don't forget that you'll have to register the index when your app starts.

Comment: Thanks for the your effort. Based on your response I've created the index. Your code did not work for me but gives me a clue. Actually I'm ok with more classes in my project. I don't want to add redundant fields to my domain objects because of some reasons, and the same denormalize my data.

Answer (score 2):

Raven can't support calculations like that inside the LINQ query, so this should work (problem clause removed):

```
var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supporters.Count)
                //.ThenByDescending(x => x.Answers.Any(a => a.IsOfficial))
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
                .Take(15);                
var result = questions.ToList();
```

If you want to include that logic, you need a field on your class called `AreAllAnswersOfficial` (or something similar). Then you can put that inside the clause:

```
var questions = DocumentSession.Query<Question>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supporters.Count)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.AreAllAnswersOfficial)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
                .Take(15);                
var result = questions.ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks one again. I knew which line was the source of the problem. I've been just wondering what kind of changes I have to do to preserve this logic. That additional field seems ok, but are there any other options, what about some custom index ?

Comment: Jarek, yes - if you don't want to have that property ´AreAllAnswersOfficial´ in your documents, you can certainly use a simple map index in which you do the calculation. Very easy in fact and you should have problems with that.